# MemoryError on Apache2 running Flask

Tags: python, apache, pandas, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm running an app on an apache2 server using wsgi and Flask on a debian config. The app is a python script that gathers data from a database and gets a pandas dataframe before displaying graphs on the front-end.

On my local machine (running windows), I can perform huge queries without any issue with a 12Gb available memory. When running the same code on the server (which has a lot more memory), I get a MemoryError from Python when we hit 500Mb in Memory.

I tried to check the limitation in limits.conf and the ulimit -a and everything is set to unlimited. I believe that could com from Flask's restrictions but I'm not sure where to start looking...

Thanks in advance for your help.
John